Как сделать индикатор зоны поражения на Unitu
Есть игра Brawl Stars, там есть индикатор зоны поражения. Я думаю привязать спрайт к персонажу и вращать его джойстиком, но как?

Если это 3d, то можно сделать мешем в любом 3d-редакторе, и повесить этот меш на персонажа.

Это будет в 3д пространстве, но все будет в 2д. Другой вопрос, как его вращать джойстиком?

Стандартными средствами Юнити, например Transform.Rotate(). Смотри/читай руководства как вращать объекты в Юнити.
